# Want to align two words in the same line in css

Tags: html, css

I have two words that will change after some JavaScript coding. They will be arrays. I can perform the JavaScript coding well, but I want them to be aligned instead of one above the other:

```
<div class="testArrayDiv">   
    <input type="text" id="testArrayText" value="aqui" class="testArrayText">
    <p id="pTextIng" class="pTextIng">Inglés</p> 
    <p id="pTextPor" class="pTextPor">Português</p>    
    <button id="btnArray" class="btnArray">Test Array</button>
</div>
```

My CSS coding:

```
.pTextIng {
    margin-left: 45%;
}

.pTextPor {
    margin-left: 45%;
}
```

The words "Inglés" and "Português" will become columns after some Javascript commands, but they are not aligned and I want them to be aligned.

Comment: `display: inline` or `display: inline-block` or `float: left` or use `flex`

Answer (score 1):

```css
.pTextIng {
    border:1px solid black;
   width:80px;
 display:inline-block;
}

.pTextPor {
border:1px solid red;
     width:80px;    
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="testArrayDiv">   
    <input type="text" id="testArrayText" value="aqui" class="testArrayText">
    <p id="pTextIng" class="pTextIng">Inglés</p> 
    <p id="pTextPor" class="pTextPor">Português</p>    
    <button id="btnArray" class="btnArray">Test Array</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`<p>` automatically inserts a line break after the text. If you do not want this you should use `<span>`. I assume you want both words on the same line as your input field, so you should put both `<span>` elements inside a `<div>` and apply `margin-left` to that.

HTML:

```
<div class="indentation">
    <span id="pTextIng" class="pTextIng">Inglés</span> 
    <span id="pTextPor" class="pTextPor">Português</span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.indentation {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 45%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you make a `div` with both `p` inside like:

```
<div class="testArrayDiv">   
    <input type="text" id="testArrayText" value="aqui" class="testArrayText">
    <div class="idiomas">
        <p id="pTextIng" class="pTextIng">Inglés</p> 
        <p id="pTextPor" class="pTextPor">Português</p>  
    </div>  
    <button id="btnArray" class="btnArray">Test Array</button>
</div>
```

And then you make this `div` element `flex` and `flex-direction: row`

```
.idiomas{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}
```

Comment: Thks! It's working, I just had to add "width: 60%;" in Css div.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add **vertical-align: top;** to fix the issue

```
.testAlign p {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    /* other styles */
}
```

and also that `<p>` tags need to be inside a `<div>`

```
<div class = "testAlign">    
    <p id="pTextIng" class="pTextIng">Inglés</p> 
    <p id="pTextPor" class="pTextPor">Português</p>
</div>
```